# Mongoose pre save hook is triggering while updating via Model.save()

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am saving a smaller unique id for mongodb documents via pre hook.

```
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
    this.refId = uid();
    next();
});
```

As far as I understand `save` hook only runs when a document is created.

But when I get the document via query and try to save it by adding some new data the unique id (`refId`) field gets updated as well.

```
const foo = Foo.findOne({refId: 'fwe23fw23'});

Foo.field = 'new value';
Foo.save(); // runs pre hook again;
```

That leads me to believe `save` hook runs on every `save()` query wheather or not its a `create` or `update` method.

How do I make sure the `refId` only created once and never changes on any update operation?

NOTE: I understand I can use `updateOne()` on the Model itself to update the document. But I want to understand why saving the document itself doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `document.save()` and `Model.create` triggers pre save hook.

You can use [isNew](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-isNew) property to check if the document is created.

```js
schema.pre("save", function(next) {
  if (this.isNew) {
    this.refId = uid();
  }

  next();
});
```

Now refId will be only created only one time when the document is created, and it's value will not change when save used.